# Uploading an image along with other datas in a form

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

i was trying to insert images omto the same table holding all other data.I couldn't upload image and also check its validation. This is how code for MODEL is.Please provide me a solution?

```
<?php  
    class Dhani_model extends CI_Model {  

        function dhani_model()  
        {  
            // Call the Model constructor  
            //parent::Model();  
        }  

        $targetpath='\images';
        $date=date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");

        $targetpath=$targetpath .$date. basename($_FILES['images']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], $targetpath);

        public function insertData($postdata)  
        {  
            $r=$postdata['name'];
            $s=$postdata['phone'];
            $p=$postdata['address'];
            $a=$postdata['days'];
            $b=$postdata['email'];
            $c=$postdata['password'];
            $images=$postdata['$targetpath'];



            $data = array(
                    'name' => $r ,
                    'phone'=> $s ,
                    'address' => $p ,
                    'days' => $a,
                    'email' => $b ,
                    'password'=> $c ,
                    '$targetpath'=> $images,

             );
            $query=$this->db->insert('registration', $data);
            if($query)
            return $query;
          }
 }
?>
```

Comment: You need a whole layer to perform that, if you want to implement it properly.

Comment: This is the error shown while i run the file Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$targetpath' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\xampp\htdocs\bodhi\application\models\dhani_model.php on line 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php  
class Dhani_model extends CI_Model {  

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function do_upload()
    {
        $targetpath='\images';
        $date=date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");

        $targetpath=$targetpath .$date. basename($_FILES['images']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], $targetpath);
    }
```

or

```
<?php  
class Dhani_model extends CI_Model {  
    private $targetpath='\images';
    private $date=date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function do_upload()
    {
        $targetpath=$this->targetpath .$this->date. basename($_FILES['images']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'], $this->targetpath);
    }
```

> [PHP Class](http://codular.com/introducing-php-classes)

Answer (score 0):

i think, it can be solved by declaring your $targetpath variable and following move operation inside the function. please try doing it.

Comment: That' really nice @sreevidya.